# Need help in listing of selected files using ssh command remotely

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am using  the following command remotely from a code and get the complete list of files from AIX box under /web/sample folder

**ssh username@10.10.10.10 ls -lLtp /web/sample**

Now I need to tweek this command, in such a way where I want to specify to get the list of file names starting with **g***

I tried like the following it didnot work 
**ssh username@10.10.10.10 ls -lLtp /web/sample g***

I am getting the complete list as above command(1st command)

Please suggest or give me the correct format to make it work

Comment: Are you using a HEREDOC?  If not, you definitely want to wrap quotes around the commands you want to run on the ssh server.  `ssh username@10.10.10.10 "ls -lLtp /web/sample g*"`

Comment: * is being expanded by the shell before being passed to ssh

Comment: @nkon, I tried quotes, no use

Comment: As @devnull stated, you also have to escape the `*` with `\*`

Comment: You are missing a slash between "sample" and "g". Should be /web/sample/g* (and yes, you should use quotes).

Comment: Its working, but I am getting the selected files with the complete path, is that possible to get only the file names in the result

Comment: Like this?  `ssh username@10.10.10.10 "ls -lLtp /web/sample g\* | awk 'FNR == 1 {print $1}"`

Comment: @gmhk: In that case, the solution proposed by "tito" should work: 'cd /web/sample && ls -lLtp g*' .

Comment: @nkon, that didnot work, as I am passing this "g\* | awk 'FNR == 1 {print $1}" to the UNIX box from Java code

Comment: Ahh sorry about that..

Answer (score 2):

Quote the command so that it is not expanded locally, and change directories on the remote end:

```
ssh username@10.10.10.10 'cd /web/sample; ls -lLtp g*'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
ssh username@10.10.10.10 -- 'cd /web/sample && ls -lLtp g*'
```

Also, you might need to add the "d" option to ls, if g* give only one result and if the result is a directory, you'll get the content of this directory.

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax is

```
ssh username@10.10.10.10 "ls -lLtp /web/sample/g\*"
```

Comment: I don't think this is what gmhk wants. I think (s)he wants the files within /web/sample that begin with g. So you need to add a slash between "sample" and "g".